# Menu item adding 'Clients/' to url

Tags: menu-item, url, update, joomla-3.6

After the joomla update the menu item seems to be broken. In every url I see

> websitename.com/Clients/menualias

rather than

> websitename.com/menualias

However, I resolved the issue by clicking the **Rebuild** button on menu manager. After which, every menu item works correctly. But now my problem is that when I create new menu item, it gives the same error of adding `clients` to the url. Then again I have to rebuild and it works.

For example, if a menu item `alias is user-profile` then Joomla system stores the alias correctly in database but the `path is stored as Clients/user-profile`

Is there any way by which the menu url can be fixed for the new items as well?

**Joomla Version: 3.6.4**

Comment: Hi, ¿Have the new menu as parent a "client" menu?

Comment: no `Clients` is not any menu item. Don't know from where it is coming. I updated the question with the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with the menu then I found this.

https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=615&t=772029

It was helpful but not the solution.

Then I checked my **#__menu** table and there I found **com_banners_clients** and this was creating the issue.

I simply deleted that row and it worked for me.
You can check its level and if you will fix the levels then the issue will be resolved.

Note : deleting this row may effect only one thing that you will not be able to see sub menu in Banner component at admin side.